# How to show alert dialog repeatedly on tapping positive button?

Tags: android

I am building an android app which check for active internet connection on device
if there is no active internet connection , an alert dialog will popup asking for retry and quit .

I want if user clicks on retry button, app will again check for active internet connection and so on.

I am facing problem in looping this code.
Here is my code

```
if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()==null){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);

            alertBuilder.setMessage("No internet connection").setCancelable(false);

            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    // Want to run this code again
                }
            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            // negetive button action goes here
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Rates and Reviews");
            alertDialog.show();

        }
```

Comment: Why don't you wrap everything into a method and call such method again when the positive button it pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
private void checkInternet(){

   if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()==null){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);

        alertBuilder.setMessage("No internet connection").setCancelable(false);

        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                // Want to run this code again
                checkInternet();
            }
        })
                .setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        // negetive button action goes here
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Rates and Reviews");
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```